# How I can redirect my site links via an .htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

How I can redirect my site links by .htaccess file. From the links now:

> domain.com/topic/30635/name-thread-non-english

To

> domain.com/30635/name-thread-non-english

So, I want to remove: "topic" and change with each subject: "30635" and "name-thread-non-english".

What to add in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I'm sure this is  duplicate but I'm not motivated enough at the moment to find the dupe.

Comment: OP, I think it would be good if we could see your current attempt. If you do not presently know how to do this, please browse the [htaccess] tag here to see some examples. You'll not learn much if you just get it handed to you (as seems to be happening below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a rewrite rule as the following

```
RewriteRule ^topic/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [rewrite a rule](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs) to do this, something like:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([a-z\-]+)?$ $2/$3 [L,R=301]
```

Example:

```
uri: topic/30635/name-thread-non-english 
^([a-z]+)\/    == topic/                   == $1
([0-9]+)\/     == 30635/                   == $2
([a-z\-]+)?$   == name-thread-non-english  == $3

the new url: $2/$3 == 30635/name-thread-non-english
```

Comment: Don't you need a `[R]` to make it issue a real redirect?

Comment: Yes, example updated

Comment: Thanks. Btw, some folks here tend to encourage an OP to try solving the problem on their own, on the basis they won't "learn how to learn" if they can just ask someone to do it for them every time they need a solution. You can of course help whenever you like, but it may not help such a poster in the long term.

Comment: I agree with you, i will be more careful from now